# Graph API fails to authenticate unless in private browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I have an annoying issue with O365 authentication, where I am using the same method as in the sample project at the [MS Graph Quick Start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) project.

It was working about 30 minutes ago, and actually does still work when I open the app in a private browser.

When calling the graph API, I am getting the error

> Code: AuthenticationFailure
>
> Message: Error - auth challenge needed

In the `SampleAuthProvider` `GetUserAccessTokenAsync` method when calling `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`:

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
{
    string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    HttpContextWrapper httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID, httpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
    //var cachedItems = tokenCache.ReadItems(appId); // see what's in the cache

    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
        appId,
        redirectUri,
        new ClientCredential(appSecret),
        userTokenCache,
        null);

    try
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' }), cca.Users.First());
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
    catch (Exception)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        throw new ServiceException(
            new Error
            {
                Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                Message = "Error - auth challenge needed",
            });
    }
}
```

So I tried logging out with the default method to see if I could re-authenticate, but I just never see the login screen again, and when I call the login action in the account controller, it says the request is authenticated:

```
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Signal OWIN to send an authorization request to Azure.
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
          new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
          OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}

// Here we just clear the token cache, sign out the GraphServiceClient, and end the session with the web app.  
public void SignOut()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Get the user's token cache and clear it.
        string userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        SessionTokenCache tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userObjectId, HttpContext);
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }

    SDKHelper.SignOutClient();

    // Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request. 
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
      CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

}

Again, this works fine from a private browser window. I am asked to log in, and I can query the graph API using the SDK.

I can also run the code fine in a different browser, so it is clearly something to do with the browser caching my credentials, but how am I supposed to overcome this without clearing my entire browser history?

**WHY? How am I supposed to authenticate if the code thinks I am logged in even after I sign out**  Why doesn't the `SignOut` method sign me out?

Please can someone advise, I am completely lost

Comment: Did you try closing and re opening the browser ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Yes, this is happening when I debug from VS, so it opens in a new browser instance each time

Comment: even though its a new instance you will have to close all as the session will be shared, that my be the issue for not logging out

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing the error message that an auth challenge is needed, you might want to call do like the following sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L116:

```
// Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
// If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
// The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
//
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties(),
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
```

or just call SignIn on the other controller

Also, SignOut is only part of the story. it trigger a roundtrip with Azure AD which requests your app to remove the AAD session cookies. you also need to process this callback from Azure AD, like in the `EndSession`method

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L56

I suggest you read the Readme.md of [active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) to understand to register this EndSession action with your Web Application.